# Element not Following Semantics for Filter CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dropdown menu which will blur out the rest of the screen when clicked. Said dropdown menu is supposed to be under `nav` section. However, because I'd like to blur out the rest of the page, not including said dropdown menu section, I had to take it out of the whole div (as all the other elements are now wrapped in a div with id `blur_content`). This is semantically incorrect, is there a way to achieve the same effect without breaking semantics?

My html code:

```
<div class = "dropdown_menu" id = "js_navbar_toggle">
    ....
</div>

<div id = "blur_content">
    <nav>
        ....
    </nav>
</div>
```

My script:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    let navBarToggle = document.getElementById('js_navbar_toggle');
    let blur = document.getElementById('blur_content');

    navBarToggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
        $(blur).toggleClass('blur');
    });
</script>
```

And my CSS for `blur`:

```
.blur {
    transition: all .5s ease;
    filter: blur(3px);
}
```

Comment: also any relevant CSS would do us _wonders_

Comment: @Jhecht Done! Sorry.

Comment: @insertusernamehere Done! Sorry.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine for me, what's the issue?

Comment: @Terry Semantically, it is incorrect, no? That dropdown menu is supposed to be part of `<nav>` and yet I'm pulling it out of `<nav>`.

Comment: There's no other way around it, since CSS filter applies to the entire composite of the element (including all child elements). You will *have* to take the dropdown menu out of the navigation element.

Comment: @Terry I see. I was just concerned that this may be frowned by people who see my code. Thank you for the reassurance :-) If you may, please provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, there is no way around this: the issue with CSS filter is that when you apply it, it applies to the entire rendered composite of the element, including all child elements. As you have correctly observed, you cannot "unblur" or, in general, "unfilter", a child element. If you want to achieve the effect of blurring out everything on the page (including the navigation menu) but not the dropdown, you will have to separate them into different sibling elements.